# How to separate a column by first digit

Tags: r, regex, tidyr, stringr

Say if we have a data frame looking like this:

```
name_and_age
Wesley Wycombe27 y.o.
Sally Atkinson33 y.o.
Matthew Lee42 y.o.
```

I would like to separate this into two columns, setting the data frame to look like this:

```
name                   age
Wesley Wycombe         27
Sally Atkinson         33
Matthew Lee            42
```

Until now I've been trying both with `separate()` and `extract()` as well while using `[:digit:]` and `\\d` as regex, however all my attempts had been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `extract` to capture the characters as a group.  Here, we specify the pattern to match one or more characters that are not a digit (`[^0-9]+`) from the start of the string (`^`), capture as a group (`(...)`) followed by digits as second group and not capture the rest of the characters (`.*`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   extract(name_and_age, into = c('name', 'age'),
            '^([^0-9]+)(\\d+).*', convert = TRUE)
#           name age
#1 Wesley Wycombe  27
#2 Sally Atkinson  33
#3    Matthew Lee  42
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name_and_age = c("Wesley Wycombe27 y.o.", 
         "Sally Atkinson33 y.o.", 
"Matthew Lee42 y.o.")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```